# Why can't I show confusion matrix of ensemble model majority voting approach?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've built an ensemble model with a majority voting approach. I used pretrained models to build the model.
code snippet:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

# Make predictions using the ensemble method with max voting
ensemble_predictions = [model1.predict(X_test), model2.predict(X_test), model3.predict(X_test), model4.predict(X_test), model5.predict(X_test)]
ensemble_predictions = np.array(ensemble_predictions)
ensemble_predictions = np.mean(ensemble_predictions, axis=0)
ensemble_predictions = np.round(ensemble_predictions)
# ensemble_predictions = np.argmax(ensemble_predictions)

print(ensemble_predictions.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
# Print the classification report for the ensemble predictions
print(classification_report(y_test, ensemble_predictions))
```

This code works fine, but I want to visualize this model with a confusion matrix. But that is showing error.

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets
```

It seems like this model can't be visualized with a confusion matrix. Is there any way to generate confusion matrix or something which I can use to visualize the outputs of the models?

Comment: Confusion matrix and classification report don't care what kind of model you are using, they will work as long as you feed in two sequences (true and predicted) of the same shape and contain the same labels as the values. It is not clear from your code what is the shape and content of your y_test, and what is the shape and content of the output of your models. If you provide more info on that,  maybe the source of the error will be more clear

Comment: The shapes are: ensemble_predictions = (19, 4) , y_test = (19, 4)

Comment: Check what is the content. What is your y_test? Is it a sparse matrix? Is it binary (0,1)? If so, you need to binarize your output.

Comment: Y_test is not a sparse matrix. It's an array.

Comment: You still need to apply argmax at the correct axis to your ensemble predictions.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy so you are saying I should apply argmax to both y_test and ensemble_predictions , and make the shape (19, ), right?